# Magento default paypal module does not send invoice email - will this behaviour stay?

Tags: email, invoice, paypal-standard

The default paypal module does not send the invoice email:

```
    // notify customer
    $invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice();
    if ($invoice && !$this->_order->getEmailSent()) {
        $this->_order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getIncrementId())
        )
        ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
        ->save();
    }
```

it just calls sendNewOrderEmail() which does not send anything because the NewOrder email has already been send. Is this a wanted behaviour or will it be changed?

My shop needs this behaviour because i have a eventlistener which sends the invoice mail after creating shipping.

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and this is still the same. The only good way to make this extension send the invoice email is by creating your own extension/addon which overrides this method. That way you can add the functionality to send the invoice into the extension.

Might be a pretty good idea to make it configurable as well. So add a configuration option to enable/disable sending the invoice email. If enabled, run your own code. Otherwise, just run the original code.